# RoboCopy Switch to exclude Top Level Folders

Tags: windows, command-line, nas

I have a .bat that copies folders with compressed files from one computer to a NAS.  Once they are on the NAS I go through extract then delete the .rar/.zip etc.  I dont want to keep compressed files on the NAS as it creates slightly more than double the space, but I need to leave them on the original computer. My issue is when I run the batch file it re-copies everyting. How can I prevent the re-copying of the directories that are already present, while at the same time copying the new directories as well as the files within them?

So what I want is to skip the top level directories that are already there, no matter the contents.

Comment: I am neither psychic or a mind reader and I don't like guessing.  What is in your batch file? Please [edit] the question and include this essential information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using old school windows batch scripting since you're using robocopy.  This might be a good opportunity to learn some PowerShell.  But, in the spirit of actually answering the question as it was asked ... :)

You could try using a FOR loop before the robocopy like:

```
SET SOURCE_DIR=C:\Wherever\the\directories\are
SET TARGET_DIR=\\nas\wherever\the\directories\are\going

FOR /D %%d IN ("%SOURCE_DIR%\*") DO (
  IF NOT EXIST "%TARGET_DIR%\%%~nxd" (
    ECHO Copying "%%~d%" ...
    REM robocopy command for copying directory [ "%%~nxd" ] goes here
  )
)
```

Comment: Hopefully, that's accurate syntax.  I don't have a Windows system in front of me at the moment.  If it doesn't work as-is, then the problem might be with the quotes in the `FOR` statement or with the contents of the `%%~d` variable.  If it doesn't work please let me know what the output was and I'll try to correct the answer ASAP.